# What is the time information on the G1000 MFD map during a hold?

Tags: holding, g1000

I just completed an ILS approach and went missed.  I followed the published missed approach and entered the hold.  When I entered the hold, on the MFD map a timer-like display was on top of the "aircraft" e.g. 00:00

The timer display did not increase after being in the hold for about 5-10 minutes.  I even started the timer from the TMR/REF softkey on the PFD to see if it would change the display on the MFD, and it still remained at 00:00.  Does anyone know what this timer display on the MFD during a hold is?

Comment: Is it possible that the fuel totalizer was not reset, and the G1000 thought your aircraft was out of fuel? That sounds like the range ring behavior.

Comment: A timer on the MFD would probably be for your Top of Descent - could be due to several previous actions on what the FPL contained before and during your hold.

PS - G1000 as primary means of navigation for an ILS hold? :D

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an Expect Further Clearance (EFC) timer. You didn't mention the aircraft type but there are several references to it online: [Garmin service advisory](http://garmin.blogs.com/aviationalerts/2015/03/service-advisory-1507-rev-b-published-hold-can-be-shown-on-the-wrong-side.html); Seneca V [impressions](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2013/February/20/Exclusive-first-look-Seneca-goes-G1000); Archer manual [quoted in a forum](http://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/unpublished-hold-programming-in-g1000-gns530w.115575/page-3#post-2312192). My G1000 experience is in a C172 and I've never seen it there (I can't find it in the manual either) but the features are different depending on the aircraft, so it's possible that EFC timing just isn't in the C172 version.

Comment: Related: [Expect Further Clearance](https://www.flyhpa.com/2011/11/holding-with-the-g1000/)